# SQL Update to second database is not writing when column is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which I'm using to get the right category to the right ad in a new database, However some of the affected rows might have multiple categories while some might not, research gave me the info to use the 'table.column + your_data', It seems that this came with a sideeffect though as it does not update NULL columns even though it says that the right amount of rows were effected..

The SQL:

```
MERGE INTO sites.dbo.ads
USING (
        SELECT e.name
        FROM Database1.dbo.education AS e
        INNER JOIN releducationcategory AS re ON e.educationid = re.educationid
        INNER JOIN category AS c ON re.categoryid = c.categoryid
        INNER JOIN string AS s ON c.categoryid = s.identifier
        WHERE (s.string = 'Biologi, Fysikk & Kjemi') AND (e.site = 'sd')
     ) AS source
  ON Database2.dbo.ads.name COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS = source.name COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
       SET sites.dbo.ads.category = ', biologi-fysikk-kjemi';
```

That update is running fine when the column is NULL but when there's already a value it'll just overwrite.. and when I change it to below:

```
SET sites.dbo.ads.category = sites.dbo.ads.category + ', biologi-fysikk-kjemi';
```

It just updates rows which does not have the value NULL.. however it does say that the same amount of rows were effected.. What do? Should i make CASES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing comma separated values is almost always a bad idea, but if you insist on doing it, this should work:

```
SET sites.dbo.ads.category =
    COALESCE(sites.dbo.ads.category + ', ','')
    + 'biologi-fysikk-kjemi';
```

This will also avoid having the first item (when switching from `NULL` to non-`NULL`) from starting with a comma.

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is that, per the ANSI standard. `NULL` + string = `NULL`. You *could* turn that off, but it's not recommended:

[`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx):

> Controls whether concatenation results are treated as null or empty string values.
>
> **Important**
>
> In a future version of SQL Server `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will always be `ON` and any applications that explicitly set the option to `OFF` will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why it's a bad idea? For future knowledge..

Are some of the ' in the wrong place?
COALESCE(sites.dbo.ads.category + ', ')
    + 'biologi-fysikk-kjemi'; should it be like that? or am I just reading stuff wrong?

Comment: It makes writing searches more complex (and such searches tend not to be able to use indexes), it makes updates and deletions more complex.

Comment: @Jesper - and yes, I missed a `'` out, I've added it back in.